# Release/Flush ifconfig pool of OpenVPN server

Tags: debian, networking, ip, openvpn, dhcp

I've been conducting some tests with my OpenVPN which apparently resulted in the exhaustion of my `ifconfig pool`. Now when I try to connect to the server, it logs:

```
Thu Mar 30 13:46:11 2017 client/<ip>:<port> MULTI: no free --ifconfig-pool addresses are available
Thu Mar 30 13:46:11 2017 client/<ip>:<port> MULTI: no dynamic or static remote --ifconfig address is available for client/<ip>:<port>
```

How do I flush/release IPs from the pool?

On a Debian stretch with `OpenVPN 2.4.0`, `OpenSSL 1.0.2k`

Answer (score 0):

A simple restart of OpenVPN should do this unless you have set something to make it track IPs over restarts.

/etc/init.d/openvpn restart

Comment: Although the option is valid, I doubt that OP would have wasted time asking about it if that was a suitable solution.